# RF connector between mobile phone and transmitter = complete shielding?

Tags: mobile, rf-power, rtl-sdr, hackrf

When connecting mobile to transmitter with RF cable:

Does RF connector provide complete shielding for the transmitter signal ?

Does it  prevent the mobile from receiving other signals from other sources ? Is it possible to shield transmitter while still receiving other signal sources?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried it out?  You're not going to get much in the way of answers unless you give us a direct question.  Shielding is just what it sounds like:  shielding.  The shield on the coax does prevent signals from coming in from the side, but there are varying degrees of protection depending on the quality of the feedline cable.  Give us some more details and you may attract more than downvotes.

Comment: Welcome to Amateur Radio Stack Exchange.  I suggest you take the tour if you haven't already, to see how this one works:  https://ham.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: @ransh you come here, ask **one** question, get a single downvote, and act like *we* owe you something? Talk about sense of self-importance. Wow. Your question shows a lack of own research, and attempt of your own, to understand the problem at hand. The *right* thing to do is to downvote it and do nothing. The nice thing to do is leaving a comment explaining stuff. And that happened. Still you act like you're an insulted 13year old. Anyway, your question hasn't gotten any better, so I'll add my own downvote. Not out of spite, just because your question is neither well-researched nor shows that

Comment: … that you even read the rules here. Have a nice day!

Comment: I have edited the question. I did a research the best i can before comung here and asking this question. Please tell me where can I learn more and what should still be edited in my question after the last edit. Not sure why this "hard" comments. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean removing the antennas from each device, and connecting them directly with a piece of coax? Yes, that does provide complete shielding. Though you'd want an attenuator to avoid overloading or possibly damaging the receiver.

Unfortunately this will also render the phone incapable of receiving other signals. No way around that with a passive device, due to [reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_(electromagnetism)).

Comment: Does this method can also assure that transmitter signal(base station) are shielded?

Comment: Is there any way to prevent transmitter interfer others while still recieving other recieved signals in mobile phone? Thx

Comment: @ransh Making the transmit power extremely low is probably the simplest solution. If the phone is not far away, you can probably transmit into a dummy load and it will still work. Otherwise you'd need a third radio with an antenna and a connection to the cabling between the transmitter and the phone which repeats signals from the outside to the inside, but not the other way.

Comment: Phil, I think that by splitting antenna phone, and getting one of the antenna out of Faraday cage, we can receive outside signal , while still receiving the signal from the station inside the Faraday cage . Right ?

Comment: @ransh Yes, but then the phone will transmit outside of the Faraday cage also.